# trigger in oracle stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I have a requirement like this: I have to select a certain number of records from an Oracle table using a stored procedure. I will capture the entire resultset in ref cursors, but at the same time I have to update a flag in the selected records ( the ones stored in ref cursors).

So I want to know whether this is possible in stored procedure. If yes, then what do I have to use e.g. triggers?

Thanks in advance

Comment: We need more details about your requirement?  Do you want to include the changed column in the result set?  Do you want the change to be committed before the result set is returned?  Or is the flag to be updated only after the records have been processed?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Here are my detailed requirement
Actually the number of records in the table are quite high, so I am calling the stored procedure in a loop and in each iteration i am selecting a set of records. Now in order to avoid the duplicate records selection i am updating the flag once i have selected the records so that they are not selected in next iteration. 
Hope i have cleary mentioned my requirements. Just wanted to make sure that we can do this in a stored procedure, if yes then i can spend some time on it..or else think of a different approach

Comment: Do you need to RETURN a ref cursor or do you process the lines in that stored procedure?

Comment: @Vivek - no, you still have not clearly specified your requirements.  If you read the responses you'll see people are still asking questions or making assumoptions.   You are expecting us to spend our time answering your question.  The least you can do is spend some time explaining what it is your are trying to achieve.   I suspect there is a much more efficient way of implementing this but I am not certain because I am still not sure exactly what your process is doing.

Answer (score 1):

A cursor doesn't "capture" or "store" anything. To store something, use a PL/SQL table.
Probably the closest thing to what you want to do:

```
DECLARE
  type t_foobar is table of foobar;
  v_foobar t_foobar;
BEGIN
  UPDATE foobar SET flag=1 WHERE foo=bar AND flag=0 AND rowum<=10;
  SELECT * FROM foobar BULK SELECT INTO v_foobar WHERE flag=1;
  UPDATE foobar SET flag=2 WHERE flag=1;
  COMMIT;
  /* process v_foobar here */
END;
```

I'm doing two UPDATEs here so that in a concurrent environment, every session selects und updates different rows. (E.g. for a airplane seat reservation system)

Comment: I have one doubt, will this concept of rownum work if the first 10 rows are already marked and need not to be selected

Comment: Yes, that's what the `AND flag=0` is for. It returns only rows that have not been handled. Make sure to put an index on that flag-column, and think about error handling. If your processing fails in the provided version, you are not going to find the failed rows any more...

Comment: Vivek: the rownum filter is applied by Oracle AFTER every other filter, so don't worry.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to ensure multiple processes do not select the same rows?

SELECT FOR UPDATE NO WAIT might be your best option.
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10472/static.htm#CIHHIIID

While that's 11.2 it will work for earlier versions of Oracle, like 10g.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you will not "capture the entire resultset in ref cursors", a ref cursor is a **pointer** to a result set. In effect, what you are returning is a query that will (or technically MAY) by executed by whatever receives it.

I'd forget the ref cursor and go with a [pipelined table function](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/9i/PipelinedTableFunctions9i.php). That way the procedure can process the records (ie flag them as updated) as it returns them to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

Ref cursors are non-modifiable, as they exist only in memory. They are a reference, as indicated by the name. You will have to perform updates separately.

Comment: Hi All,
again explaining my requirements:
I have a table which contains several thousand of records. I have to process all those records, but i cannot process all the records at same time, i can only process 1000 records at a time. So i am using a stored procedure and calling the same in a loop. Now to avoid the duplicate records to be fetched again, i am updating a flag for all those records which i have selected in one iteration, that's why i have to update the all of the records which have been selected in a stored procedure.